# nmap in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nmap

idk wheather to post such a silly question in this forum.just out of interest i want to know few things.

can i use `nmap` in `ubuntu 13.10`

is `backtrack` another distro like `ubuntu` i have heard that `backtrack` is based on ubuntu`

if backtrack comes with bundle tools like `nmap`

is `nmap` and other tool like `wireshark` found in `ubuntu software center` is powerful  as `backtrack`

if `backtrack` is updated to `kali linux`?

Comment: Please restrict your question to single issue only. This is helpful to everyone

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How to install nmap on Ubuntu/Debian systems

```
# sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Install nmap in yum packaged system Centos/RHEL

```
# yum install nmap -y
```

Install from rpm package

```
# rpm -ivh nmap{version_of_package}.deb
```

Install from .deb package file you have downloaded

```
# dpkg -i nmap{version_of_package}.deb
```

Scan a single host

```
# nmap ubuntu.example.com
```

Scan a hostname for more information about the host

```
# nmap -v ubuntu.example.com
```

Scan multiple IP Addresses

```
# nmap 192.168.1.77 192.168.1.99
```

Scan range of IP addresses using wildcard (*)

```
# nmap 192.168.1.*
```

Scan entire subnet 255.255.255.0

```
# nmap 192.168.1.0/24
```

Scan for range of IPs

```
# nmap 192.168.1.33-99
```

Find the OS & Version of remote hosts using nmap

```
# nmap -A 192.168.1.77
```

This will output more information about a host and its ports and operating systems and Version

```
# nmap -v -A 192.168.1.77
```

Scan for particular port number

```
# nmap -p 22 192.168.1.99
```

Scan for TCP port 443

```
# nmap -p T:443 192.168.1.99
```

Scan for UDP port 82

```
# nmap -p U:82 192.168.1.99
```

Scan multiple ports

```
# nmap -p 443,82 192.168.1.99
```

Scan for all ports using wildcard(*)

```
# nmap -p "*" 192.168.1.99
```

To watch the all packets send and receiving

```
# nmap --packet-trace 192.168.1.77
```

Know whether a host is protected by firewall or not :
To scan firewall protected for a host

```
# nmap -PN 192.168.1.99
```

Scan firewall protected for a network

```
# nmap -sA 192.168.1.77
```

To know the interface and route

```
# nmap --iflist
```

Exclude single host

```
# nmap 192.168.1.10-100 --exclude 192.168.1.77
```

Exclude multiple hosts

```
# nmap 192.168.1.10-100 --exclude 192.168.1.77,192.168.1.95,192.168.1.99
```

To perform a fast scan

```
# nmap -F 192.168.1.77
```

To know more commands use command man

```
# man nmap
```

Comment: Excellent explanation! Respect to author!

Answer (score 2):

> can i use nmap in ubuntu 13.10

Yes you can use nmap in Ubuntu.Run the below command to install nmap,

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

> is backtrack another distro like ubuntu i have heard that backtrack is based on ubuntu

Yes, Backtrack is based on Ubuntu 10.04 but Kali linux is based on debian.

Comment: i am not looking for installation cmd of nmap dude.what i am looking for is some info about nmap in ubuntu and if backtrack is another distro that comes with nmap

Comment: Backtrack is a distro specially designed for hacking.So it comes with preinstalled hacking tools.But Ubuntu is not comes with that tools.You have to install that kind of tools manually.Nmap found in USC is as much same as the tool found in backtrack.

Comment: thank you so much.so kali linux is like ubuntu as its also .deb

Comment: yes, you can install .deb file on kali linux because it's based on debian.